# All databaseex properties come back NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have some troubles in SQL Server. This is for a class and I'm new to SQL Server. Anything I run with:

```
select databasepropertyex ('database', 'property')
```

They all come back null. I'm using Windows Authentication Mode. I'm trying to check `IsSingleUser`, `IsEmergencyMode`, `IsShutDown` just to name a few... anything I can do that will actually return the values of these database properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN,

> If the database is not started, properties that the SQL Server retrieves by accessing the database directly instead of retrieving the value from metadata will return NULL. That is, if the database has AUTO_CLOSE set to ON, or the database is otherwise offline.
>
> **Permissions**
> If the caller of sys.databases is not the owner of the database and the database is not master or tempdb, the minimum permissions required to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY DATABASE or VIEW ANY DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE DATABASE permission in the master database. The database to which the caller is connected can always be viewed in sys.databases.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823(v=sql.120).aspx

Also, please check if you misspelled database name or property name. In such case, databasepropertyex also returns NULL.

Comment: I've checked auto_close by select * from sys.database auto_close is off on all databases.